# I’m in the middle of creating a quiz but some parts have me scratching my head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make it so that every time the user clicks the answer under the list of choices buttons more time is added to the countdown and when the user clicks on any other one of the choices time is deducted from the countdown. Also when the user clicks on anyone of the choices whether its the correct answer or not they then move onto the next question and only one question is displayed at a time within the form. If anyone can take a look at my current code and give me some suggestions about what things I could possibly do that would be amazing. By the way I have a separate js file named questions.js which lists the questions, choices, and answers in the form of an array.

Heres the html file and theres some jQuery on there as well :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  

<head>  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">  
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
 <title>Bleach Quiz</title>  
 <script  
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"  
 integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="  
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  
 <nav>  
 <ul>  
 <li id="highscore"><p>Highscore</p></li>  
 <li id="time"><p id="currentTime"></p\></li>  
 </ul>  
 </nav>  
 <div id="Start">Start Quiz</div>  
 <div id="form">  
 </div>  
 <script src="questions.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript">  
 var index = 0;  
 var firstQuestion = questions[index];  
 var h = $("<h>");  
 h.text(firstQuestion.title);  
 var c1 = $("<button>");  
 var c2 = $("<button>");  
 var c3 = $("<button>");  
 c1.text(firstQuestion.choices[0]);  
 c2.text(firstQuestion.choices[1]);  
 c3.text(firstQuestion.choices[2]);  
 c1.on("click", function(e){  
 alert(e.target.innerText)  
})  
 $("#form").append(h);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c1);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c2);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c3);  
 $("#form").append("<br>");  
 var secondQuestion = questions[1];  
 var h = $("<h>");  
 h.text(secondQuestion.title);  
 var c1 = $("<button>");  
 var c2 = $("<button>");  
 var c3 = $("<button>");  
 c1.text(secondQuestion.choices[0]);  
 c2.text(secondQuestion.choices[1]);  
 c3.text(secondQuestion.choices[2]);  
 c3.on("click", function(e){  
 alert(e.target.innerText)  
})  
 $("#form").append(h);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c1);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c2);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c3);  
 $("#form").append("<br>");  
 var thirdQuestion = questions[2];  
 var h = $("<h>");  
 h.text(thirdQuestion.title);  
 var c1 = $("<button>");  
 var c2 = $("<button>");  
 var c3 = $("<button>");  
 c1.text(thirdQuestion.choices[0]);  
 c2.text(thirdQuestion.choices[1]);  
 c3.text(thirdQuestion.choices[2]);  
 c2.on("click", function(e){  
 alert(e.target.innerText)  
})  
 $("#form").append(h);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c1);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c2);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c3);  
 $("#form").append("<br>");  
 var fourthQuestion = questions[3];  
 var h = $("<h>");  
 h.text(fourthQuestion.title);  
 var c1 = $("<button>");  
 var c2 = $("<button>");  
 var c3 = $("<button>");  
 c1.text(fourthQuestion.choices[0]);  
 c2.text(fourthQuestion.choices[1]);  
 c3.text(fourthQuestion.choices[2]);  
 c1.on("click", function(e){  
 alert(e.target.innerText)  
})  
 $("#form").append(h);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c1);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c2);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c3);  
 $("#form").append("<br>");  
 var fifthQuestion = questions[4];  
 var h = $("<h>");  
 h.text(fifthQuestion.title);  
 var c1 = $("<button>");  
 var c2 = $("<button>");  
 var c3 = $("<button>");  
 c1.text(fifthQuestion.choices[0]);  
 c2.text(fifthQuestion.choices[1]);  
 c3.text(fifthQuestion.choices[2]);  
 c3.on("click", function(e){  
 alert(e.target.innerText)  
})  
 $("#form").append(h);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c1);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c2);  
 $("#form").append("<br>")  
 $("#form").append(c3);  
 $("#form").append("<br>");  
 </script>  
 <script src="script.js"></script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Here's the JavaScript file:

```
var startElt = document.getElementById("Start");  
var timeleft = 75;  

function startQuiz(){  
  var bankaiTimer = setInterval(function(){  
    document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";  
    timeleft -= 1;  
    if(timeleft <= 0){  
      clearInterval(bankaiTimer);  
      document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = "Its Over"  
    }  
  }, 1000);
}  
startElt.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest moving all that inline JavaScript in your HTML to your JavaScript file as well. That should allow that code to modify that same `timeleft` variable that the countdown code uses. It'll then simply be a matter of adding to or subtracting to it. You'd also want to move your countdown text code into its own function so that when you add/subtract you can also update the screen with a new time remaining message.

Comment: How should I then create functions in Javascript that access the jQuery variables and functions that I have made ? Sorry I am new to this Javascript.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking, but any of the code you have inline in the script tag will work inside of your JavaScript file.